# Are there any ready-made solutions for the editor of book covers for the site?

Tags: javascript

I'm redesigning the website of book publishing, the customer asked me to add a simple editor for book covers. That is, the user enters the title of the book, the author, uploads his book, and then edits his cover. From the editor options: upload your image, insert additional text (select a font from the list, size, color), select a background color. Canva button is not suitable because registration is required for the user. Tell me if there are ready-made solutions for this task, maybe some `js` libraries?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using this [Syncfusion Card control](https://www.syncfusion.com/javascript-ui-controls/js-card)